# Combining json files without created a new list of objects every time

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-3.7

I have a dynamic amount of `.json` files being generated in a folder, that I would like to combine to one final json file.

This is my current code:

```py
import json
import glob
import os

read_files = glob.glob(save_dir + "page_data*.json")
read_files.sort(key=os.path.getmtime)
output_list = []

for f in read_files:
    with open(f, "rb") as infile:
        output_list.append(json.load(infile))

with open(save_dir + "table_data.json", "w+") as outfile:
    json.dump(output_list, outfile)
```

So with above, I look for all my the generated .json files in my folder, and combine them into one final file called: `table_data.json`.

In this example, two files have been appended:

```
[
    [{
        "0": "Text",
        "1": "More text",
    }, {
        "0": "Yes",
        "1": "No",
    }],
    [{
        "0": "Text from another file",
        "1": "Yes",
    }, {
        "0": "Second file",
        "1": "Text",
    }]
]
```

As you can see, for each file, a new `[]` set is created.

How can I combine the json files dynamically, but without creating a new json list object `[]` every time? I only want one list of objects, like so:

```
[{
    "0": "Text",
    "1": "More text",
}, {
    "0": "Yes",
    "1": "No",
}, {
    "0": "Text from another file",
    "1": "Yes",
}, {
    "0": "Second file",
    "1": "Text",
}]
```

Comment: Use `output_list.extend` instead of `output_list.append`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier than you might expect! Just change one word in your code:

```
for f in read_files:
    with open(f, "rb") as infile:
        output_list.extend(json.load(infile))
```

Using `output_list.`**`extend`** instead of `append` will add elements one by one, instead of adding the entire json object as one list element.